# Possible ways to do like UITableView Design with multiple columns.?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, master-detail

I have gone through many of sites. But I didn't get the way to achieve it .
 As so far , I came to know that using UITableView we need to make custom cell with some stuff of code  and lots of stuffs on some custom design like GridView etc

> https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView [Here it is ok to modify but I'm actually looking for within 1 class file].

.
Here is actually I need to look to do design as like below image .[image]

Here, I have done so far by using [THIS LINK](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Grid-View-in-IPhone-using-UITableView-1665.php). but it is not useful for me.

if anyone knows please share your thought , any help or suggestion should be appreciable.

Comment: Your question isn't related to Xcode.

Comment: I had a similar requirement. I made a section headerView, which includes first two rows. For the rest I subclassed UITableViewCell added labels and then gave a background border for them which will look very similar this. Give it a try.

Comment: Sounds good . Thanks for your response. Will go through by your way . Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a your own Custom UITableViewCell and design it in such a way it contains multiple UIButtons arranged Horizontally and seperated by seperators image . Here each UIButton will be representing a seperate column and also different selector methods must be added as target for different buttons within the cell . The UIButtons that are vertically aligned in different rows must have the similar Selector. In order to differentiate between buttons you can set their tag as the indexPath.row for the respective row .

I hope this might solve your problem :)

Comment: Its good , Thanks for your answer . If i go through it ,It consumes many objects right.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a grid like view you could very well use a UICollectionView and do some tweaking with design.

Comment: Thanks . I will give a try on it . basically I'm not looking for such a view. I just need to do design like above , that design should be acceptable for the iPad app [ I mean it should look and feel good]